# How to run an input txt file through a C file to an output txt file in Command Prompt?

Tags: c, command-line, stdout, command-prompt, stdin

I am trying to run a test file through my C program, but I seem to be making a mistake.

My program is stdin/stdout, so it should work. When I run it in the normal "Build and Run" popup of Code Blocks, by copying the file contents in, it runs perfectly fine. But when I run it in command prompt like

```
input.txt < maze.c > output.txt
```

it isn't working. I put all three files on the desktop as well, and used cd Desktop to get there. When I run that line, it opens the input file, and leaves the output file empty.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure about your compiling process? The 'maze.c' suggests, that the file is not binary, but jsut the source code. Also, are you on linux/windows?

Comment: C is compiled language. It means, you need to take the source code, use compiler on it to get .exe file, then run the exe file.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my error in that. Running maze.exe make much more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command should be :

> `$ prog_name < input_file > output_file`

not :

> `$ input_file < prog_name > output_file`

Also, `maze.c` is the source code, not the compiled program.

Comment: So, given what is written in the question, OP probably wants `maze.exe < input.txt > output.txt`

Comment: That is specific to my program and what I would run! Thanks hyde!